# How to safely break the strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

The following example is known to break the strict aliasing rule and therefore produce different results with and without optimization:

```
int foo( float *f, int *i ) { 
    *i = 1;               
    *f = 0.f;            
   
   return *i;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    
    std::cout << x << "\n";   // Expect 0
    x = foo(reinterpret_cast<float*>(&x), &x);
    std::cout << x << "\n";   // Expect 0?
}
```

But accessing an object through a reinterpret_cast-pointer from a different type is UB anyway.

I now wonder how to modify the example to still break the strict-aliasing rule but without the UB because of the reinterprect_cast

Comment: At least with gcc it effectively compiles without strict aliasing rules by default when building without optimisations: [-fstrict-aliasing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) - `... In particular, an object of one type is assumed never to reside at the same address as an object of a different type, unless the types are almost the same... The -fstrict-aliasing option is enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os.`. And in `-fno-strict-aliasing` mode by definition any such code should work as there were no aliasing restrictions in the language.

Comment: Isn’t the point of the strict-aliasing rule that it’s merely an optimization—*i.e.*, it changes the behavior only of programs whose behavior is undefined?

Comment: The indeed question was how to generate two pointers of different type that alias each other without UB. Is that possible at all?

Comment: @DavisHerring: The Standard uses the term "Undefined Behavior" as a catch-all to describe, among other things, situations where most implementations should process a construct consistently, but where it might sometimes be useful to allow *some* implementations to process some corner cases in ways that deviate from behavior *that would be defined absent such allowances*.  The intended meaning was, essentially "If the a compiler's customers wouldn't care about how a corner case is handled, the Committee shouldn't either".  Search for "C99 Rationale" for more info.

Comment: @supercat: Aside from the fact that C99 is not the language under discussion, that purported intent is controversial and/or outdated.  My understanding is that the C committee would be glad to reduce the (infinite) leeway given to implementations in the case of undefined behavior, but I don't think any practical means is known of (ever) doing so.

Comment: @wimalopaan: It is possible to have certain pointers of different types alias without undefined behavior (trivially, `T*` and `const T*`).  However, use of such pairs does not "break the strict aliasing rule", safely or otherwise.

Comment: @DavisHerring: The reason the Standards don't provide a way of working around the limitations that would be posed by the "strict aliasing rule" if it were 100% enforced is that "configure your compiler to allow the the existing syntax to serve that purpose"  works just fine with almost any compiler.  What is horrible and outdated is the failure to accommodate situations where some deviations from straightfowrad sequential processing would be acceptable, but others would not.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't actually a **difference** between the strict-aliasing rule and the "UB from `reinterpret_cast`" here: the strict aliasing rule is simply the compiler's name for the `reinterpret_cast`-related rules its optimizations assume the code is following in that mode.  (In particular, you can **evaluate** `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&x)`, but the only thing you can do with the result is cast it right back to `int*` (or some other *similar* type).  Storing through it is what "violates strict aliasing" ([basic.lval]/11).)